# How to add or increment a dictionary entry?

Tags: python, syntax

I'm currently re-engaging with Python after a long absence and loving it. However, I find myself coming across a pattern over and over. I keep thinking that there must be a better way to express what I want and that I'm probably doing it the wrong way.

The code that I'm writing is in the following form:

```
# foo is a dictionary
if foo.has_key(bar):
  foo[bar] += 1
else:
  foo[bar] = 1
```

I'm writing this a lot in my programs. My first reaction is to push it out to a helper function, but so often the python libraries supply things like this already.

Is there some simple little syntax trick that I'm missing? Or is this the way that it should be done?

Comment: As an aside, you can say `if bar in foo:` instead of `if foo.has_key(bar):`

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: +1 for using a regular expression :-)

Comment: I used has_key because I thought (mistakenly I guess) that it would make use of a hashing function to find the key rather than searching through a list, and hence be more efficient.

Thanks for the tip - I'll adjust my coding accordingly.

Comment: 4 years later, but I think this is important to say for those who may end up here from Google (like me): `if key in dict` is actually more efficient than `d.has_key(key)` and conceptually better.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

foo = defaultdict(int)
foo[bar] += 1
```

In Python >= 2.7, you also have a separate [Counter](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class for these purposes. For Python 2.5 and 2.6, you can use its [backported version](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/).

Comment: `collections.Counter` is in `2.7` http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#new-and-improved-modules

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about defaultdict. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 136):

The `dict`'s [`get()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method takes an optional second parameter that can be used to provide a default value if the requested key is not found:

```
foo[bar] = foo.get(bar, 0) + 1
```

Comment: I didn't vote it down, but I guess the original downvoter did that because it violates the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle: "foo" and "bar" are both mentioned twice.

Comment: @Tamas: Well, the OPs version mentions each of those three times :)

Comment: @Tamas... That seems a fairly extreme interpretation of the DRY principle... I usually see it referred to in the context of repeating logic - not variable names! This is a good answer by my book, as it conveys the logic cleanly and can be adapted to a number of scenarios (any default value, any function to be performed)

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer, no imports required.

Answer (score 9):

I did some time comparisons.  Pretty much equal.  The one-lined `.get()` command is fastest, though.

Output:

```
get 0.543551800627
exception 0.587318710994
haskey 0.598421703081
```

Code:

```
import timeit
import random

RANDLIST = [random.randint(0, 1000) for i in range(10000)]

def get():
    foo = {}
    for bar in RANDLIST:
        foo[bar] = foo.get(bar, 0) + 1


def exception():
    foo = {}
    for bar in RANDLIST:
        try:
            foo[bar] += 1
        except KeyError:
            foo[bar] = 1


def haskey():
    foo = {}
    for bar in RANDLIST:
        if foo.has_key(bar):
            foo[bar] += 1
        else:
            foo[bar] = 1


def main():
    print 'get', timeit.timeit('get()', 'from __main__ import get', number=100)
    print 'exception', timeit.timeit('exception()', 'from __main__ import exception', number=100)
    print 'haskey', timeit.timeit('haskey()', 'from __main__ import haskey', number=100)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Interesting - love to see some testing, though the differences you've measured are tiny! I wonder how they would be affected by having more or less duplicates? My prediction: exception version will perform best when foo[bar] += 1 usually succeeds

Comment: Increasing the duplicates improves the performance of the exception code. Changing RANDLIST to [random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(10000)] produced: get 0.0955109596252
exception 0.06258893013
haskey 0.0973930358887

Comment: how `defaultdict` compares here?

Answer (score 4):

For Python >= 2.5 you can do the following:

```
foo[bar] = 1 if bar not in foo else foo[bar]+1
```

Comment: While valid, this is not any more concise or readable than the OP's code.

Comment: @sventechie. I think you may have a very personal definition of readable and Pythonic.

Answer (score 4):

You can also take advantage of the control structure in exception handling. A `KeyError` exception is thrown by a dictionary when you try to assign a value to a non-existent key:

```
my_dict = {}
try:
    my_dict['a'] += 1
except KeyError, err:    # in 2.6: `except KeyError as err:`
    my_dict['a'] = 1
```

Comment: Just because exception handling *can* be used for control flow doesn't mean that it should.

Comment: AFAIK, doing something like dict.has_key(key) actually tries to access the key and returns False if an exception is caught.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this was tried, but if you need to append items in dict keys...

```
indicatorDict = {}
indicatorDict[0] = 'Langford'
indicatorDict[1] = 'Esther'
indicatorDict[3] = 14
```

Append items to it, be it iteratively or other types:

```
indicatorDict[0] = np.append(indicatorDict[0],'Auditorium')
indicatorDict[1] = np.append(indicatorDict[1],'Duflo')
indicatorDict[3] = np.append(indicatorDict[3],'November')
```

Printing ...

```
{0: array(['Langford', 'Auditorium'], dtype='<U10'),
 1: array(['Esther', 'Duflo'], dtype='<U6'),
 3: array(['14', 'November'], dtype='<U11')}
```

I avoided 3rd key in Dict to show that if needed keys can be jumped from one step to another... :) 
Hope it helps!